# Add attribute to the DynamoDB table in node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a table through .yml file in a server-less project. In which I want to add four field in table -> 1. email,  2. name,  3. city,  4. profile,
But when I am running the project it throwing a error that is "The number of attributes in AttributeDefinitions are not equal to the number of attribute in KeySchema. As I equal these number of attribute in both then my table creating in the DynamoDB. But here are only two attributes.

Below is my .yml file

```
  Resources:
   users:
     Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
     Properties:
       TableName: users
       AttributeDefinitions:
         - AttributeName: email
           AttributeType: S
         - AttributeName: name
           AttributeType: S
       KeySchema:
         - AttributeName: email
           KeyType: HASH
         - AttributeName: name
           KeyType: RANGE
       ProvisionedThroughput:
         ReadCapacityUnits: 1
         WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

How can I create my table with my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB is schemaless, you only define the partition and sort keys of your table and your indexes if any.

Non-key attributes are not defined at creation time, as each item is allowed to contain its own individual schema. Once your keys are defined correctly, you are free to store any other attributes at will on a per item basis.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Lee for giving me this information.

Comment: This information worked for me.